# Email tag and tel tag is not working in laravel project

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my laravel project i have a google map with markers, when clicking on marker ,their location details will be dispalyed on infowindow. But for email and phone number i want to add `tel` tag and `email` tag, Such that on clicking on it corresponding actions can be taken.

Following is my code

```
var html =   cname + "<br/>" + cliniccity + "</br>" + clinicstate + "</br>" + clinicpin + "</br>Email:&nbsp"  + clinicemail +  "</br>Phone:&nbsp" + clinicPhone +  "</br>" ;
```

On this code `clinicemail` & `clinicPhone` is simply displaying the values. How can i add tel tag and email tag to this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: I have seen this, but please help me to link in code

Comment: If you get this email and phone number then a user must be login

Comment: You already have HTML in your code, just link `clinicemail` and `clinicPhone`.  What exactly do you need help with? (You might also want to change your question's topic, since there is no email or tel tag in your code.)

Comment: @kerbholz Can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add mailto: and tel: tag before the clinicemail and clinicPhone.

```
var html =   cname + "<br/>" + cliniccity + "</br>" + clinicstate + "</br>" + clinicpin + "</br>Email:&nbsp; <a href=`mailto:`"  + clinicemail +  "`></a></br>Phone:&nbsp; <a  href=`tel:`" + clinicPhone +  "`></a></br>" ;
```

Comment: Sorry bro ,its not working it is showing mailto and tel with data

Comment: you have not added a href tag here

Comment: Now email id and phone number is not displaying

Comment: just use the apostrophy  ( ' ) instead of tilda ( ` ) i believe that's causing the problem for you.